# Spring MVC RESTAPI : How jackson converts list of objects to JSON format and send the response

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, rest, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm learning Spring MVC RESTAPI, Can anyone explain how the Jackson library automatically converts the list of objects to the JSON format. I can't figure out when the Jackson library comes into play and how the conversion happens from a list of objects to JSON format because I am sending the Response as a List but somehow it converts it into JSON. Can someone explain the process? Thank you.

**The Jackson Library I've added :**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Model Class :**

```
public class Country{

int id;
String countryName; 

public Country(int i, String countryName) {
    super();
    this.id = i;
    this.countryName = countryName;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}
public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
}  }
```

**Controller Class :**

@RestController
public class CountryController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/countries", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public List getCountries()
{
    List listOfCountries = new ArrayList();
    listOfCountries=createCountryList();
    return listOfCountries;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/country/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public Country getCountryById(@PathVariable int id)
{
    List listOfCountries = new ArrayList();
    listOfCountries=createCountryList();

    for (Country country: listOfCountries) {
        if(country.getId()==id)
            return country;
    }

    return null;
}

// Utiliy method to create country list.
public List createCountryList()
{
    Country indiaCountry=new Country(1, "India");
    Country chinaCountry=new Country(4, "China");
    Country nepalCountry=new Country(3, "Nepal");
    Country bhutanCountry=new Country(2, "Bhutan");

    List listOfCountries = new ArrayList();
    listOfCountries.add(indiaCountry);
    listOfCountries.add(chinaCountry);
    listOfCountries.add(nepalCountry);
    listOfCountries.add(bhutanCountry);
    return listOfCountries;
}  }
```

When I request the *getCountries()* method, It just send the JSON data even though the Datatype of the method is List, How this is happening?